# How to update object data based on string input in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, prisma

I want to update an object's value based on the input of a string that's related to an object key, how should I go about this with typescript?

```
const objData = { // random value
  A: 11,
  B: 13,
  C: 53,
  innerObj: {
    AStatus: true,
    BStatus: false,
    CStatus: true,
  },
};

type Item = 'itemA' | 'itemB' | 'itemC';

function processObj(item: Item, obj: typeof objData) {
  if (item === 'itemA') { // <- duplicate
    obj.A = 5;
    obj.innerObj.AStatus = true;
    return obj;
  }

  if (item === 'itemB') { // <- duplicate
    obj.B = 5;
    obj.innerObj.BStatus = true;
    return obj;
  }

  if (item === 'itemC') { // <- duplicate
    obj.C = 5;
    obj.innerObj.CStatus = true;
    return obj;
  }
  return
}

processObj('itemA', objData);
```

For instance, the input is `itemA`, and only `A` related objData gets updated.

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArAIgQyqmBeGBvGA9ATAE6pgAmIAtjAG6oA2ArgKYBQMMAggFwwBGAQBpOMAEL8BAZlFcAwvwCsssQEswYViQDySfrjFduAZQxRmEflBJs5XCWfSX%20AMyYRW9hU4tWYNnZiAL6iwQDc7OxQAJ4ADqwwAJJQrLQ4AORqqdTcGTAAPjBZOeL5RSVp8hmR7K7MYMBQauAwcSQgwKwQEHqIABTZafwpacJw%20gHxrCCuEyjoqACUeOpzgznYWJlDuRkr%20EQwADwAtDAUzHGMasDoHA7zAHTc2DBKkY8IiE8aWrpIF6%20SxvQKsT4OEisCwkMDzCHBKJcNTrXZbHalfZ4QjEM4XK43O6pIzPcRvD4k76-TTaPpPcTAiCg2zgklQmFw74IpEwFEwDZpdHFXbVA44k7nS7XW73SmA%20TkiFcKl-WnyxnMthK0jQ5iw%20EhMTsvVgdiI9jtTrdXpIfqVPbjb5oDBLcJAA)

Comment: How do you want to generalize the relationship between `"itemA"` and `"AStatus"` and `"A"`?  Is it just string manipulation like `"item"+k`, `k+"Status"` and `k`?  Or is there some mapping somewhere?

Comment: If it's just string manipulation then maybe [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N9EjVN) would work for you. If that addresses the question fully, I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I not sure if it's the right way to use generics, because, the field to be updated is related to string itself, let me try it out.

Comment: @jcalz Hi! Please do write an answer, I think you solved my problem, tho not with this case regarding prisma, but a similar situation. But this approach seemed a bit hacky, in a situation where we want to update object data from a string input, what would you say?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  If you want to [edit] the question with a [mre] that demonstrates whatever situation you're talking about instead of the one currently in the question, maybe I could look at it.  Or if you're happy with this and want to open a new question with the new situation, that would be fine too.  But right now I don't really understand what "update object data from a string input" means enough to suggest anything.  And can you explain what makes the approach above "hacky"? Is it the string manipulation? If so, what's the alternative... lookup table?

Comment: Looking at this again, it doesn't seem like you need generics at all (can you explain why you want generics per se?).  I can change my original solution to [this](https://tsplay.dev/mq59rm).  And if you'd rather see a lookup table instead of string manipulation, you could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/WoG8gW).  Let me know if either of these works for you.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the other two solution, but wow, thank you for the refreshing takes, I have edited the question, but maybe you can help improve the description of the title a bit, the solution does apply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the relationship between the `item` parameter and the key names of `obj` and `obj.innerObj` is programmatically determined by string manipulation, such that there is a property key `k` of `obj` corresponding to a property `k+"Status"` of `obj.innerObj` and to the value `"item"+k` of `item`, then you can refactor your `processObj` function to use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types).  Template literal types allow you to represent some string literal manipulations at the type level.  Here's one way to do it:

```
type Keys = Exclude<keyof typeof objData, "innerObj">;
// type Keys = "A" | "B" | "C"

function processObj(item: `item${Keys}`, obj: typeof objData) {
  const k = item.substring(4) as Keys; // need to assert here 
  obj[k] = 5;
  obj.innerObj[`${k}Status`] = true;
  return obj;
}
```

The `Keys` type uses [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) to filter the [keys of](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) `objData` to remove `"innerObj"`, leaving us with the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) `"A" | "B" | "C"`.

For the rest of it, we're using template literal types to perform string concatenation at the type level.  The type of `item` is `` `item${Keys}` ``, which evaluates to `"itemA" | "itemB" | "itemC"`. We can calculate `k` from `item` by stripping the initial `"item"` prefix from it; the result is of type `Keys`, but the compiler can't verify that.  Thus we just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that `k` is of type `Keys`.

We can just set `obj[k] = 5` with no compiler warning because the compiler understands that `obj` has a `number` property at all keys in `Keys`.  And we can also set `` obj.innerObj[`${k}Status`] = true `` with no compiler warning, because the compiler understands that a [template literal string value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) can have a template literal *type*, and that the type of  `` `${k}Status` `` is `` `${Keys}Status` ``, which evaluates to `"AStatus" | "BStatus" | "CStatus"`.  And the compiler knows that `obj.innerObj` has a `boolean` property at those keys.

So this all works as desired.

---

On the other hand, if the relationship between `item` and the keys of `obj` and `obj.innerObj` is arbitrary, then you can't necessarily use string manipulation to map between them.  In this case, you would want something like a lookup table to represent the mapping, whatever it is.  Such an implementation might look like this:

```
const propLookup = {
  itemA: "A",
  itemB: "B",
  itemC: "C"
} as const;
const statusLookup = {
  itemA: "AStatus",
  itemB: "BStatus",
  itemC: "CStatus"
} as const;
type Keys = keyof typeof propLookup;
// type Keys = "A" | "B" | "C"

function processObj(item: Keys, obj: typeof objData) {
  obj[propLookup[item]] = 5;
  obj.innerObj[statusLookup[item]] = true;
  return obj;
}
```

The `propLookup` and `statusLookup` objects are just maps from valid `item` values to the corresponding properties of `obj` and `obj.innerObj`.  They are using [`const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) so the compiler keeps track of the string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the values.  If we left off `as const` then the compiler would infer just `string` for the values, which doesn't help us.

This also works as desired; the compiler understands that `propLookup[item]` is a key of `obj` with a `number` value, and that `statusLookup[item]` is a key of `obj.innerObj` with a `boolean` value.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUPkkvAPbBQAuSpARgFYAiIlISAvHkgPTdIBOIYABNSYJADdMAVwhFiSAIIAuJAEY1AGnnEAQqrUBmbQqQBhVQFZjOpAEtgwCPwDyDVQVPFFAZVaVpKFVKflkTL10-FkDVADNMKAhw0zMogKCkELDbAF9wnIBuQmJQSFgEZD9+BwBzAFkhOxhpDBY7cjxihUoATxhkAGkIHqgOJABRAA94DGlhCAAeAGth0ljMvog1mgZmVk0kACIHJ1cGQ4A+ItNeDf6kIZGxw8VDpAAfI903z8OzQ9ssWkwHglHawCQMH4pEQUCgbnoAAo7JQIGBVAADFFogAkuEeUByGIOdHowU221JexAAEpOl4SOQqEglmNsWAAHRQaS0KjVYA1REAFjpIFGBIKPD4TggwkypCQYsS-GoAAtnMhbMRSQBtJYAXTGlmuXlJHJOzgROoxeKWOTSgQxhs4WQgJtM-AgAX4ENJ7qQOS6xChMOg8IYiIA5OzFJGSbsWLSivJA-JStA4IgkAAZUikJbSGAAFRAtAwyAItjIFGoIZgufzhbGni8MdUL0OyQU7P0X07WvsqLAFiO-1yitG1ao-qn1Co0SgDYLMGbA7bR18-kC-YZPfbkS3UB3raHI7+DqP47FjJr-t69wJYxWPW29626zrS8L-tub4ew1GTgOw+PsQL+AFAWBUFwUhaFYXDJF2VUAl4zJO53x2JhEzpFtTF1T882XHV2X1Z0kGNAczQtM56B1ed0i-GBiKHUixldf1iE9b1fQYf1U1MEN4IRKMYzjTDqRpZMU0IHIgA)